# Cannot access $wpdb, comes back NULL

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm developing a rather simple plugin using the Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate. Utilizing AJAX, I set up a action based upon a button press that's supposed to remove an item from the custom database table I set up. The AJAX works, the button works, the call to the operating PHP file works.

However, when I get to the operating PHP file where some simple database manipulation is supposed to take place, nothing happens. The file at this point consists of:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name['database_name'] = $wpdb->prefix . 'database_name';
echo var_dump($wpdb);
echo var_dump($table_name);
echo var_dump($wpdb->prefix);
```

That's it right now. And these var dumps come back as "NULL," "database_name", and "NULL."

What am I doing wrong here? In the few others files involved in this project everything works fine. What did I break? If it's an AJAX thing and Wordpress handles AJAX differently, I'd love to see a good tutorial for it, because the few I've found that handle Wordpress AJAX explicitly have been outdated and/or broken.

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com . But it's not recommanded to create a new database table then, before to create a question there, test if you cannot use custom post type instead : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

Answer (score 0):

it means you are calling `$wpdb` even before wordpress can initialize it, or you're doing something even more weirder

it can be done something like this,

jquery

```
$('body').on('click', '.some-click-handler', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {'action':'test_ajax'},
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      },
    });
});
```

your php ajax handler, though you should add more security like nonce

```
//wp_ajax_nopriv for non logged-in user
add_action('wp_ajax_test_ajax', function() {
    global $wpdb;
    wp_send_json( $wpdb );
});
```

checkout wordpress ajax docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)